# How to make size tailored label with envlab?

Tags: letters, envlab

According to the [package guide](http://www.cs.brown.edu/system/software/latex/doc/elguide.pdf) I should be able to declare label sizes in the preamble of the document like in this example:

```
\documentclass[12]{letter}

\usepackage{envlab}

\SetLabel{63mm, 46mm, 10mm, 8mm, 3mm, 3, 6}
\begin{document}
\startlabels
\mlabel{}{%
    givenname surname \\
    Address line \\
    postalcode \\
    Country
}
\mlabel{}{%
    givenname surname \\
    Address line \\
    postalcode \\
    Country
}   
\mlabel{}{%
    givenname surname \\
    Address line \\
    postalcode \\
    Country
}
\mlabel{}{%
    givenname surname \\
    Address line \\
    postalcode \\
    Country
}   
\mlabel{}{%
    givenname surname \\
    Address line \\
    postalcode \\
    Country
}
\mlabel{}{%
    givenname surname \\
    Address line \\
    postalcode \\
    Country
}   
\mlabel{}{%
    givenname surname \\
    Address line \\
    postalcode \\
    Country
}
\mlabel{}{%
    givenname surname \\
    Address line \\
    postalcode \\
    Country
}   
\mlabel{}{%
    givenname surname \\
    Address line \\
    postalcode \\
    Country
}
\mlabel{}{%
    givenname surname \\
    Address line \\
    postalcode \\
    Country
}   
\mlabel{}{%
    givenname surname \\
    Address line \\
    postalcode \\
    Country
}
\mlabel{}{%
    givenname surname \\
    Address line \\
    postalcode \\
    Country
}   
\mlabel{}{%
    givenname surname \\
    Address line \\
    postalcode \\
    Country
}
\mlabel{}{%
    givenname surname \\
    Address line \\
    postalcode \\
    Country
}   
\mlabel{}{%
    givenname surname \\
    Address line \\
    postalcode \\
    Country
}
\mlabel{}{%
    givenname surname \\
    Address line \\
    postalcode \\
    Country
}   
\mlabel{}{%
    givenname surname \\
    Address line \\
    postalcode \\
    Country
}
\mlabel{}{%
    givenname surname \\
    Address line \\
    postalcode \\
    Country
}   
\end{document}
```

However when I do that I get:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.12 }
```

and if I move the `\SetLabel` to after `\begin{document}` I get:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.13 \mlabel{}
              {%
```

What have I missed? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `\SetLabel` has seven arguments, not a list argument:

```
\SetLabel{63mm}{46mm}{10mm}{8mm}{3mm}{3}{6}
```

Comment: Yea I just noticed... I guess I am having one of those days... :)
But thanks!