# Change font size in envlab?

Tags: fontsize, envlab

I am using the `envlab` environment to create and print address labels. Unfortunately, I have some long names that I am addressing letters to, and not all of them will fit on the label. I'd like to decrease the font size in order to compensate. Does anyone know how to do this? The standard tricks I know (putting `\tiny` in the beginning of the document, adding `8pt` to the options of `\documentclass{letter}`) don't seem to work.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27862/how-to-make-size-tailored-label-with-envlab

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). If the link mentioned in the above comment does not solve your issue, please compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case to be able to use size changes such as `\small`, they need to be enclosed within a group. So, the second example below with `\small Given Name Surname` does not produce any size changes, but the third example `{\small Given Name Surname}` does:

[image]

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{envlab}
\SetLabel{63mm}{46mm}{10mm}{8mm}{3mm}{3}{6}

\begin{document}
\startlabels

\mlabel{}{%
    Given Name Surname \\
    Address line \\
    postalcode \\
    Country
}   
\mlabel{}{% This \small has no effect
    \small Given Name Surname \\
    Address line \\
    postalcode \\
    Country
}   
\mlabel{}{% This \small has as effect
    {\small Given Name Surname} \\
    Address line \\
    postalcode \\
    Country
}   
\end{document}
```