# Printing Envelopes and Labels

Tags: python, envlab

I am wondering what people use to print envelopes and shipping labels? Namely, I had to send yesterday 40-50 big envelopes. Normally, I use [labels](http://texcatalogue.sarovar.org/entries/labels.html) but I find it default sizes avery 5360 to be too small for the shipping address on the big envelope (I ended up using it for return address). Since, I have not seen an obvious way to adjust the size without playing with macros itself I played for a while with [envlab](http://texcatalogue.sarovar.org/entries/envlab.html). With all due respect to Boris Veytsman who is probably lurking somewhere on this forum I could not get thing do even the examples from his user manual (I am using TeXLive 2009 on this particular computer). At that point I felt I had option of doing a quick hack in pure TeX to get the output that I like or using something else. I settled with [Python LableNation script](http://LabelNation) which uses pure PostScript as a back end. I do not know what I would do if I had to use a special character but for basic shipping was good enough. Unlike envlab I could use the same `dat` file I used with labels package (obviously if I could get envlab to do what I wanted I would write a script to feed data to the tex source code).

P.S. Ever since I started frequenting this forum I found my self pushing TeX/LaTeX more and more and I am feeling a bit adventurous. Key value driven ConTeXt
looks more and more appealing. And Lua, I have a bad feeling I will learn Lua...

Edit: I just checked [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37139/change-font-size-in-envlab) and the answers from that question compiles without any problems. It looks like there is a problem with envlab documentation. I was typing

```
\mlabel{%
```

following the official documentation while in the working example I see

```
\mlabel{}{%
```

instead.

Comment: well, I do lurk here sometimes.  Do you still have problems with envlab?

Comment: I knew you would be here :) As I said I ended up using LabelNation instead of envlab since I needed to ship those 40 envelopes quickly and the damn thing just worked. Luckily, I didn't need special letters like \v{s} (correct letter instead of s in my family name). Now, I have that working example from the other question with correct syntax I can read your documentation more carefully. That should be enough to give me a head start when I try to customize labels next time. Thanks for taking a notice of my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For labels I have been using [ticket.sty](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ticket). It is nicely customizable and I could easily use a scripting language or Excel to fill the label commands. Recently I have been working on labeling small C5/C6 directly, including the digital stamp.

Comment: I just checked out ticket.sty and I think you misunderstood my question a bit. I was looking for postal/envelope labels. However ticket.sty looks very useful.

Comment: For printing directly on envelopes ticket.sty may not be optimal but for labels to be put on envelopes it is quite nice. I used it to generate name tags. For envelopes I created my own template, I also include in the PDF the electronic stamp from Deutsche Post.